# Leaf disease - new leaves on pear tree dying - able to identify from photos?

Tags: trees, diseases, leaves, fruit-trees, pear

Does anyone know what is killing these leaves on this pear tree (Comice pear if that matters) and how to treat it?

[image]

[image]